Hash as primary Key versus BigInt, read/write performance
I have an unlogged postgresql table holding three columns: 'key' of type varchar (255) hosting immutable sha256hex strings, 'created_at' of type timestamp without time zone and 'json' of type text.
To give context, this table is used for managing a database cache fed by caffeine (java in memory cache library) upon eviction events.
So far, I have defined 'key' as being the primary key.
Alternatively, I could have add a surrogate key (some bigint auto generated value) and add a unique index on the 'key' column.
I read few interesting articles here about the usage of surrogate keys and most of them advise their usage in a different context, when performing joins with other tables or when the 'key' column is subject to updates.
Since it will never be my case, I was wondering what was the read/write performance penalty of using 'key' as primary key versus adding a surrogate (primary) key ?
To let you know, I only peform two queries :

the first one select table entry by key
the second add a new entry.

I have read things about index fragmentation but I believe it would affect both solutions, am I getting it right ?

I think the main reason to create a separate ID is (as you write) for joins. Performance-wise, a primary key in Postgres is the same unique index, like any other: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS

Unrelated note to your queries: Don't you also want an update or delete on the entries? If the table stores cached data, then you probably want to do a cleanup on outdated entries.

IMO, for larger tables or if write becomes a bottleneck, switch to bigint primary key with a unique index on key. And for moderate-sized cache table, keep key as primary key.

You are right, updating those entries occur as well (I forget to mention) but when using key as primary key, I don't deal with physical deletion. When reading entries, I have a criteria based on duration to decide if an entry is relevant or not. If it is, I retrieve it, if not I add/update what can be updated according to the scenario. In the end, I will endup with a lot of entries that may never be read/updated anymore.

Have you considered storing your SHA256 hashes as bit strings instead of text? They'll be significantly shorter.

@mustaccio hashes cannot guarantee uniqueness or retrieval of correct value. For the same reason, the built in Hash Index also does not support unique constraint. (It would be faster, though, if you could somehow guarantee there won't be any hash conflicts)

@mustaccio without knowing what the keys are, we might not be able to tell whether SHA256 will produce shorter strings. If the keys are something along the line of "<entity>:<id>:<operation result>" (e.g., animals:12345:get) they will be quite short.

@SimonKocurek Mustaccio did not suggest hashing anything. The OP is using hashes as keys (see first paragraph of the question), those values should be stored using bit(256), not varchar(255).

Bit strings seems not to be natively supported by the programming interface (Java Persistence Api) I am using to read/write those entries. It appears that custom support is feasible within JPA but then I am wondering the benefit of the column type change (varchar 255 to bit (256)) if it adds one addittional conversion per entry read/written.

@FreeBSDEnthousiast The benefit is smaller storage size, in particular also for the index backing the primary key, making lookup faster. The conversion barely costs anything.
